# jQuery Ajax PHP redirecting to another page

Tags: php, jquery

JavaScript file:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "ajax.php",
 data: dataString,
 success: function(r) 
   {
     $("#div").html(r);
   }
});
```

I want to redirect  the page to `new.php` on success condition so in the `ajax.php` file I used `header('Location:new.php');` but instead of redirecting to page `new.php` it is loading the content of `new.php` in the `div`.

What changes do I need to make in order to redirect the existing page to a whole new page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "ajax.php",
 data: dataString,
 success: function(r) 
  {
    window.location = 'new.php';//window.location.href = 'new.php';
    //$("#div").html(r);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

By placing a header in the file you're requesting via AJAX, you're simply re-routing your AJAX request to that URL. You're *not* going to redirect the user's browser, since the AJAX request is happening in the background.

Instead, you need have your redirect in your JavaScript file, specifically inside of the success clause:

```
//From Pragnesh Chauhan's answer (modified): 
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "ajax.php",
 data: dataString,
 success: function(r) 
  {
    window.location.href = 'new.php';
    //$("#div").html(r); Useless since you're redirecting.
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you even want to use jquery / ajax for this function as the whole point using ajax is to be able to reload a part of a page without having to refresh the whole page or redirect to a new page.

Why not just post the form data to the same page and use the PHP to do what is needed and then redirect to new.php using PHP or post the form to new.php and do what is needed with the posted data on that page.

Comment: I want some data to be be processed by ajax.php and echo that data to a div named "div",after printing this I want to redirect to new page with a time lag.so that the user can see the message before directing to a new page

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "new.php";
```

Try this in `success()`