# why do we need to place the source name to redirect?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, redirect

I saw in another post ([jQuery Ajax PHP redirecting to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355699/jquery-ajax-php-redirecting-to-another-page)) that when using ajax to redirect to a PHP page we need to set an event like so :

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "ajax.php",
 data: dataString,
 success: function(r) 
  {
    window.location = 'new.php';//window.location.href = 'new.php';
    //$("#div").html(r);
  },
});
```

However it's not clear to me :

1. why do we need to indicate the " url: "ajax.php","
2. should the url entry contain the name of the current file from which we're redirecting ?
3. if i'm redirecting from a file called abc.html ?  I should just replace the ajax.php with abc.html ?

Thanks!

Comment: You read this probably wrong. What you see here, is you do an AJAX call with post data (the datastring) to ajax.php. If that post is completed (read the succes) it redirects you to the propper location. This is how you should read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me explain you clearly

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(r) 
{
   window.location = 'new.php';//window.location.href = 'new.php';
   //$("#div").html(r);
},
});
```

$.ajax this function actually makes ajax request to files ..

your questions

1. why do we need to indicate the " url: "ajax.php","
2. should the url entry contain the name of the current file from which we're redirecting ?
3. if i'm redirecting from a file called abc.html ? I should just replace the ajax.php with abc.html ?

answer #1

this line means url: ajax.php ... 
where actually you want to make ajax request in this case code making ajax request to file ajax.php

answer #2

no this is totally separate from redirecting ..

answer #3

no if you change ajax.php with abc.html then it will not redirect..after changing it will make ajax request to abc.html now

and for redirecting ...
use simple code

```
window.location.href = 'filename'; // replace filename with any file like new.php
```

Comment: Thanks @Zebi Rajpot  ! 
is there a way for me to replace the above code that will both redirect AND post (the input fields from the current page)  to a target.php  page ?

Comment: yes you can do both things with same time 

here is a code which you can use to post fields data

var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', $("#input1").val() );

$.ajax({
  url: 'target.php',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    window.location.href = "filename where you want to redirect";
    alert(data);
  }
});

now this line adding post file data to formData
fd.append( 'file', $("#input1").val() );
use this method to add more fields and send it to target.php

Comment: you are very beginner so learn more about jquery ajax from w3school here m providing you link

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: if you found my answers useful then please hit on up arrow but to say this answer is useful .. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is not for redirect. You can redirect only with this code:

```
window.location.href = 'new.php';
```

AJAX is to make requests to the server by asynchronous mode.
The answers to your questions:

1. Is the url to make requests. You don't need it if your only purpose is redirect.
2. No if you don't will use it.
3. NO. Only with `window.location.href` you can redirect

Comment: A better solution would probably involve no JS at all and just work by submitting an HTML form.

Comment: Why submit a form? If OP doesn't want to involve in JS is better a simple `<a href="new.php">` . Submit a form makes no sense.

Comment: Because the existing Ajax is POSTing something to the server before trying to load a new page.

Comment: OP doesn't need AJAX, he found an article that he doesn't understand good. OP needs to redirect to a page.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, sorry for not explaining myself properly before, I don't just want to redirect , I also what to *post* info from input fields i have on the current page 
I'm using AJAX because i'm editing an existing page code, and my preference is to minimize changes on the page.

Comment: Your question is bad asked. if you don't understand $.ajax() maybe you need to read documentation (maybe xD). Take a tour: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

What this code does is that it calls ajax.php, and when this call succeeds (which is always in this case, unless ajax.php has syntax error or sends error header), it executes the success function. Success function does the redirect to new.php.

If you just want to do a redirect in javascript, all you have to do is:

```
window.location = 'http://somewhere';
```

you probably don't need all this code you posted above.

Comment: but will this also post the input fields from the current page  to the "http://somewhere" page ?

Comment: no. but the code you posted won't either. however you can grab the input fields in javascript, and send them via get to the page you're redirecting to. it all depends on what you're trying to achieve.